# Invalid "drawable sw600dp land"

Tags: java, android

It says "invalid resource directory name" when I create a folder "drawable-sw600dp-land" under res.

I'm using Eclipse with the latest Android SDK.

Comment: Please read this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: @MysticMagic Thanks for your help and it worked... Sorry for my dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to Clean and Build your project. That should work.

Because your folder name seems correct.